# VBA Checkbox pop-up that sets filter?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm curious if it's possible in VBA excel to have a popup checkbox that will filter results. As an example a popup box (similar to an input box) comes up with several choices you can "check" that will then cause it to filter a specific column with just the items you checked.

Also I should mention this is something I plan to use in connection with a macro I'm running to help automate the filtering process. So I cannot just setup a checkbox on the spreadsheet itself. I'd need it to be an actual pop-up.

I'm not very versed with check boxes or their use in VBA so I'm not sure if this is possible or not. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!!
-Deke

Comment: You'll need to design a `UserForm` with a `ListBox` control showing your available filter values, and configure the listbox to render `CheckBoxStyle` so that each item in the list gets a checkbox. Then you'll need to write a procedure that determines whether the form was cancelled or okayed, and apply the desired filter accordingly (or not). So yes,it's possible... just many, many, *many* things to cover - more than can reasonably fit an answer box on this site.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks! I've got a starting point to work with. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Excellent resource! Thanks that's very helpful!